# STL Geometry - Distinguishing between locations that are outside or inside the geomtry

Tags: matlab, geometry

Let us consider the following example. This is a standart Matlab function, so everyone can access "BracketWithHole.stl".

```
figure
gm = importGeometry("BracketWithHole.stl");
pdegplot(gm,"FaceLabels","on")
```

[image: Example or a STL]

My goal is this: The STL geometry is to be "inserted" into a 3D matrix.
The areas of the matrix that lie outside the geometry should have a value of 1; those that lie inside the geometry should have a value of 0.

Here is a 2D example: All places in the matrix that are "empty" receive a 0; all others receive a 1.
[image: 2D-Example]

Edit: length, height and width of the 3D-matrix need not be the same

Comment: Is this what you want? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158078/load-stl-file-in-matlab-and-convert-to-a-3d-array/51158671#51158671

Comment: Yes, that should be, what I was looking for :)
I have a question regarding the code. What is meant by "get the range of your data from the STL file". Is this e.g. 50x30x20?

Comment: Maximum and minimum values of the coordinates, the range.  e.g. ~[-0.1, 0.3] for your x in the first figure. The blue box in your second figure, essentially. You gotta define that, such that it contains the entire mesh.

Comment: And where do I get "fv" from? Unfortunately I didn't understand this,

Comment: its a structure with faces and vertices, one of the most common ways of storing STL type data. `fv.faces` contains the indexes of each point that makes triangles `(nTriangles,3)`, `fv.vertices` contains the points themselves `(npoints,3)`. 3 because its a 3D mesh.

Comment: So It should be "fv = importGeometry("BracketWithHole.stl")" in my code, right? But then I get the error: "Unrecognized method, property, or field 'vertices' for class 'pde.DiscreteGeometry'."

Comment: No, it should not, it is your responsibility to make this matrix the right format to input to the code, or change the code to fit your data type.

Comment: Or use this: https://github.com/AnderBiguri/TriangleCT/blob/56a5248e769155a971d9d12429e770af549253ac/Utilities/third_party/STLRead/stlread.m

Comment: That seems to work very well so far. Hopefully last question: What exactly is "yourboundariesSize" in the line "img=reshape(in,yourboundariesSize);" I tried "yourboundariesSize = size(yourboundaries)", but it is not.

Comment: Try to understand the code. Test it, read the variable names. You will relize that the result `in` is a `1D` array, but you wanted a 3D array, so you need to reshape it. What shape do you want to make it?

Comment: You simply render your STL into your 3D matrix using [triangle voxel grid rasterization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74251621/2521214) and then simply flood fill the interrior ...

Comment: @AnderBiguri Now I understand, it is the dimension in x/y/z. The problem I am fighting with is that `in` only contains zeros. The boundary limits are not wrong, are they? `boundaries_x= [-0.1,0.3];
boundaries_y= [0,0.2];
boundaries_z= [0,0.2]; 
[x,y,z]=meshgrid(boundaries_x,boundaries_y,boundaries_z);`

Comment: @AnderBiguri I also tried it with e.g. `boundaries_x= linspace(-0.1,0.3,10)`, but it didn't help.

Comment: No, but I suggest you read `meshgrid` documentation, as you are calling it wrong. With the linespace (for all 3 of them) should be right, but you may need more than 10 points.

Comment: I have used a simple cuboid as the STL. Nevertheless, the variable `in` contains only zeros as entries, no matter how many intermediate values i use with linspace. So this code does not seem to work (for me).