STL to binary mask conversion
I have an STL file and I would like to make a binary mask from it in MATLAB, that would be defined similar to this:
stl_mask = zeros(size(stl_file));
stl_mask(stl_indices) = 1

I have searched around and there is a stlread function that lets me visualize the STL file in MATLAB, but I am a bit lost on how to work around it. This is the STL file that I'm using. For the moment, I have just this small code to visualize the STL file:
clearvars
filename = 'example.STL';

[v, f, n, c, stltitle] = stlread(filename);
figure;
patch('Faces',f,'Vertices',v,'FaceVertexCData',c);


Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158078/load-stl-file-in-matlab-and-convert-to-a-3d-array/51158671#51158671
